# Error loading documents when viewing a firestore collection on firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am facing a very strange issue with cloud firestore. I have a collection named 'advertisements' and when I see the collection on firestore console it gives error Error loading documents. I tried to add a collection named 'ads' and its working fine and also all other collections are working fine. But I don't know why this strange thing is happening with collection 'advertisements'.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Are there any error messages showing in the debug/javascript console of your browser. If not, there's not much we can do about it here and I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: When I check console net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT this is what I get with 404 error to the advertisement collection.

Comment: Are you running an Ad blocker or something like that? If so, you might want to disable that. I'd also recommend testing in incognito mode of your browser, and/or in a different browser, to see if this is a client-side problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I tried on Safari and it is working fine also in incognito mode in chrome it is working fine. But I am not using any ad blocker extension.

Comment: I removed the VPN extension and now the issue is resolved. Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved and the main cause of the issue was a VPN extension installed in my chrome browser. So for anyone who is facing such an issue try to turn off any VPN or ad blocker extension and it will resolve the issue.